# Microsoft Teams Connector unable to save configuration

Tags: microsoft-teams, office365connectors

I'm trying to build a Microsoft Teams connector that I have sideloaded into my team while developing. I've set up a [testing config page on S3](https://wsk-teams-test.s3.amazonaws.com/teams_configure.html) and have pointed my app manifest to it. When I click the save button, it stays stuck on the "Setting up your connector" spinner for a while, before saying "Unable to save connector configuration. Please try again."

The Javascript of the config page should be visible through the S3 link above; my app manifest is below. After looking at a few similar questions, you'll note that the `contentUrl` is included by wildcard in `validDomains`.

```js
{
  "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/json-schemas/teams/v1.7/MicrosoftTeams.schema.json",
  "manifestVersion": "1.7",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "id": "0b73c39a-db1d-43eb-81bd-3813bef33713",
  "packageName": "<redacted>",
  "developer": {
    "name": "Developer",
    "websiteUrl": "<redacted>",
    "privacyUrl": "<redacted>",
    "termsOfUseUrl": "<redacted>"
  },
  "icons": {
    "color": "color.png",
    "outline": "outline.png"
  },
  "name": {
    "short": "Test",
    "full": "Test"
  },
  "description": {
    "short": "Test notifications",
    "full": "Test notifications"
  },
  "accentColor": "#FFFFFF",
  "connectors": [
    {
      "connectorId": "0b73c39a-db1d-43eb-81bd-3813bef33713",
      "configurationUrl": "https://wsk-teams-test.s3.amazonaws.com/teams_configure.html",
      "scopes": [
        "team"
      ]
    }
  ],
  "permissions": [
    "identity",
    "messageTeamMembers"
  ],
  "validDomains": [
    "wsk-teams-test.s3.amazonaws.com",
    "<redacted>"
  ]
}
```

I'm not able to get any more detailed information when attempting this via the desktop Teams app, but in the browser I see this error in the console:

```js
2020-09-02T23:05:20.879Z Received error from connectors {"seq":1599086774636,"timestamp":1599087920857,"flightSettings":{"Name":"ConnectorFrontEndSettings","AriaSDKToken":"<redacted>","SPAEnabled":true,"ClassificationFilterEnabled":true,"ClientRoutingEnabled":true,"EnableYammerGroupOption":true,"EnableFadeMessage":false,"EnableDomainBasedOwaConnectorList":false,"EnableDomainBasedTeamsConnectorList":false,"DevPortalSPAEnabled":true,"ShowHomeNavigationButtonOnConfigurationPage":false,"DisableConnectToO365InlineDeleteFeedbackPage":true},"status":500,"clientType":"SkypeSpaces","connectorType":"0b73c39a-db1d-43eb-81bd-3813bef33713","name":"handleMessageError"}
```

Thanks for any guidance you might have. If I can get in touch with someone from Microsoft privately, I'd be happy to provide the `<redacted>` information.

Comment: Thank you for reaching out to us We will investigate and if we require further information we will reach out. Best regards, Teams Platform

Comment: Could you please confirm the below:
1. Are you calling microsoftTeams.settings.setsettings() in your connector configuration page? 
2.  Could you please confirm if you have added contentUrl in valid domains of your connector in connector dashboard? 
3. Please confirm if all the URL's you are trying to load are https url's.
4.   Could you also check if you have set actions in connector dashboard properly and also confirm if you have added microsoftTeams.settings.setValidityState(true) before registering save handler?

Comment: 1. I linked the configuration page above, you should be able to see the code with "View Source" in Chrome. This will show that we're calling `microsoftTeams.settings.setSettings`.
2. I have a wildcard value in `validDomains` that should cover the `contentUrl` we provided. I'm reluctant to post it publicly.

Comment: Can't edit, so here's the rest:
3. I'm not sure what you mean by "URLs you are trying to load", the configuration page is served over HTTPS and doesn't call any other URL. `validDomains` does not specify HTTPS in the wildcard, but the `contentUrl` is HTTPS.
4. I'm not sure what you're asking with "actions in connector dashboard," but yes we are calling `setValidityState(true)`. That is in the page source

Comment: Could you please share the entire manifest along with the actual id's so that we can test it at our end?

Comment: @Gousia-MSFT Do you have a professional email address where I could reach out to you privately to provide that information? I'd prefer not to post it publicly here.

Comment: Please send it to microsoftteamsdevATmicrosoft.com

Comment: Thanks, I just sent an email.

Comment: We looked at the manifest and we noticed that the url you are trying to load is not added as a valid domain in the connector configuration page. Could you please try adding your content url as a valid domain in the connector dashboard? Also, please take a look at the connector setup page [here](https://github.com/OfficeDev/microsoft-teams-sample-connector-csharp/blob/master/TeamsToDoAppConnector/Views/Connector/Setup.cshtml) and try calling registerOnSaveHandler before doing SetSettings?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue is fixed by adding the content url in valid domains list in the [Connector Developer Dashboard](https://outlook.office.com/connectors/home/login/#/publish).

Answer (score 0):

As recommended above: This issue is fixed by adding the content url in a valid domains list in the Connector Developer Dashboard.
This helped me understand the direction of the problem.
But my accidental mistake was due to the lack of the prefix https://
**Be sure to add https:// prefix to your domain**